# Get Active SIM(s) only from dual sim phones

Tags: android, telephonymanager, dual-sim, telecom-manager

I've seen many similar questions on StackOverFlow almost addressing the same issue i.e. Ability to get Active Sim information "only" from a dual sim phone.

By Active SIM it is meant that any SIM that has been disabled from Device Dual Sim settings shouldn't be treated as an active SIM.

Following APIs/Methods I've tried already and they all return both the SIMs as Active:

1. TelecomManager.getCallCapablePhoneAccounts() // Returns both the accounts as active accounts
2. SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() // Returns both the subscriptions as active subscriptions
3. TelephonyManager.getSimState(0/1) // Returns 5, SIM_STATE_READY for both the SIMS

Note:

1: I've 2 valid SIMS in my phone. One is disabled by Dual Sim Manager in device.

2: I'm testing currently on Huawei Y9 2019.

3: Default Dialer App and True Caller app somehow are able to detect the changes in SIM active status and update their functionality/view accordingly.

Any idea, how to get this information reliably and accurately?